# how to solve for the unknowns given two equating polynomials in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have, for example, the following polynomials to be equated, and I need to determine the unknowns c1, c2, c3, respectively. How can I do this automatically in mma, especially when there are many terms involved?

```
x+2*x^3+4*x^5==(c1+c2)*(x+2*c2*x^3)+(4-c1)*c3*x^5
```

Many thanks.

Edit: ideally, I want to equate the coefficients of left and right for the terms with equal exponents in x. Then solve this system of equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this has to be true for all `x`, you could use [SolveAlways](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SolveAlways.html) (not tested)

```
SolveAlways[x+2*x^3+4*x^5==(c1+c2)*(x+2*c2*x^3)+(4-c1)*c3*x^5, x]
```

Comment: Of course mma has a built in solution for this sort of problem :-).

Comment: `SolveAlways` is a handy (and unappreciated) command. I set an [exam question](http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/2009/Exam/Exam2009Solutions.nb) a couple of years ago that asked the students to balance [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium#Production) reaction. A problem most easily solved with `SolveAlways`.

Comment: @Simon "_Stay seated and do not talk until the examination supervisors verify that the correct number of notebooks have been uploaded._" ... May I go to the toilette, PLEASE?

Comment: @belisarius You're never allowed to go to the toilette in the last 15mins of an exam. And we can't exactly trust the students to upload to the ftp site by themselves. (I fixed this in the next year's notebooks. [Check out the upload button](http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/2010/Assignments/8.nb)!)

Comment: @Simon SolveAlways approach is nice for balancing chem reactions, but try it with your reaction, but adding (making up chemicals) NaO_2 on left side and FeCrC on right side. Not trivial to convert SolveAlways result to a balanced reaction. Can get a good result with Minimize.

Comment: @Daniel: The solution using SolveAlways is in the first link I provided... How would you set up a Minimize approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
p1 = x + 2*x^3 + 4*x^5;
p2 = (c1 + c2)*(x + 2*c2*x^3) + (4 - c1)*c3*x^5;

Solve[CoefficientList[p2, x] == CoefficientList[p1, x], {c1, c2, c3}]
```

Out

```
 {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 1, c3 -> 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want even in more complicated situations.

```
eq = x + 2*x^3 + 4*x^5 == (c1 + c2)*(x + 2*c2*x^3) + (4 - c1)*c3*x^5;
list = CoefficientList[eq /. Equal[k__, l__] -> Plus[k, -l], x];
vars = Variables@list;
Solve[list == Table[0, {i, First@Dimensions@list}], vars]

Out[1] := {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 1, c3 -> 1}}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but assumes that all symbols are independent (i.e. no parameters)